# css frameworks for android desktop applications

Tags: android, css, frameworks

We have css frameworks like bootstrap while working with normal web applications.I found some of the css frame works like PhoneGap .But they are web frame works.But are there any css frameworks available for android desktop applications.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Read about Android themes here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html
It's not CSS, but it's built-in mechanism for the same aim.